# Why doesn't a panel with GridBagLayout show the content?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I wrote a little something here. It's working if I don't `backPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout);`

But without the grid bag, the content stays in the top left I maximise the screen.

With the grid bag I only get the red `backPanel` in the frame. Well, there is a gray pixel in the middle of the screen. I'm assuming that's my panel, but I can't make it bigger. I tried setSize but it doesn't change. Also, I had the `panel.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());`. I'm not sure why I removed it.

My main is in the other file. The only thing it does at the moment is to call the `LoginFrame`.

#### Here is the code:

```
package first;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class LoginFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public LoginFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 300);

        JPanel backPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        backPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(500, 300);
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel label;
        panel.add(label = new JLabel("Username:"));
        label.setBounds(20, 100, 100, 25);

        panel.add(textField = new JTextField());
        textField.setBounds(140, 100, 200, 25);

        panel.add(label = new JLabel("Password:"));
        label.setBounds(20, 145, 100, 25);

        panel.add(passwordField = new JPasswordField());
        passwordField.setBounds(140, 145, 200, 25);

        panel.add(label = new JLabel("CTC Bank"));
        label.setFont(new Font("New Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 50));
        label.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), 100);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JButton button;
        panel.add(button = new JButton("Login"));
        button.setBounds(140, 200, 100, 25);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button = defaultActionKeyEnter(button, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        panel.add(button = new JButton("Register"));
        button.setBounds(240, 200, 100, 25);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button = defaultActionKeyEnter(button, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        
        
        //add(panel);
        backPanel.add(panel);
        add(backPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JButton defaultActionKeyEnter(JButton button, int desiredKeyCode) {

        InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

        KeyStroke spaceKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false);
        KeyStroke spaceKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true);

        KeyStroke desiredKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke desiredKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, true);

        inputMap.put(desiredKeyPressed, inputMap.get(spaceKeyPressed));
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyReleased, inputMap.get(spaceKeyReleased));

        inputMap.put(spaceKeyPressed, "none");
        inputMap.put(spaceKeyReleased, "none");

        return button;
    }
    
    // Unfinished code dont worry bout it...
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Login")) {
            if (textField.getText().equals("Heinz")
                    && (new String(passwordField.getPassword()).equals("password123"))) {
                // color = Color.GREEN;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong Username or Password", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                // color = Color.RED;
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cya");
            dispose();
            setVisible(false);
        }
        // panel.setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

I have seen questions about this but none of the answers were helpful in my case.

Calling the following didn't help.

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Did I maybe add it in the wrong order?

And how does the code look like to you? Would you consider this clean?

Comment: I found the issue.. "panel.setSize(500,300);".. .setPreferedSize(new Dimension(500,300)) solved the issue... and now i packed it too.. u can close the question admin..

Comment: Why are you using GridBagLayout when you’re only adding one component?  You probably want to use BorderLayout for `backPanel`.

Comment: *"`panel.setSize(500,300);".. .setPreferedSize(new Dimension(500,300))` solved the issue"* Actually it didn't, it just helped hid the problem for a while. The problem starts here: `panel.setLayout(null);` If you wish to pursue this to a robust solution, [edit] to add a [mre]. (I.E. copy/paste the `main` method to allow people to (compile &) run the code without change.) It would also help to provide ASCII art or simple drawing of the GUI at minimum size and when made larger.

Comment: For something like seen in a [screenshot of your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIMub.png) I would suggest: 1) Use a modal dialog, or more specifically in this case, a `JOptionPane`, to present the login fields and labels. 2) Expand 'CTC Bank' to 'CTC Bank Login' and use that as the title for the option pane. 3) Define the 'Login' and 'Register' buttons as the two options for the option pane. 4) Layout the label - field pairs using a `GridBagLayout` in a `JPanel` 5) Use that panel as the component the option pane displays.

Answer (score -2):

The layout of backPanel will mis-calculate the dimensions of "panel" because "panel" does not participate in layout management properly, without a layout manager of its own.

One solution to this is to use setLayout(null) also on the "backPanel", or add "panel" directly to the JFrame.

With the first suggestion ("backPanel.setLayout(null);" just after it is created), plus the following main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginFrame();
    }
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: My teacher also said he is not a fan of GridBagLayout.. but couldnt think of a solution himself.. the only thing i want from the gridBagLayout is to keep the panel in the middle of the frame/backPanel in case someone resizes the window.. 
i saw a few similar questions on here but only the GridBagLayout answer was helpfull..
BorderLayout doesnt keep the content in the middle, in full screen the center is basicaly the whole screen... i am still working on it i did change the null layout to borderlayout imma post the progress soon.. ty for the feedback guys..

Comment: @camickr Swing was not designed to require layout managers, it was designed to offer the possibility to work with or without them. There is even a Swing tutorial on this: [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

Comment: @BerryMadison *not a fan of GridBagLayout* - each layout manager has its strengths/weaknesses. You need to learn to use the appropriate layout manager of combination of layout managers to achieve your desired layout. *keep the panel in the middle of the frame/backPanel in case someone resizes the window.* - this is the default behaviour of a GridBagLayout. So your issue is how you are using the GridBagLayout. Since you haven't posted a proper [mre] we can make a suggestion on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Once again, Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. It makes the GUI more functionally usable. For example components will automatically resize or reposition as the frame is resized which is a requirement of this question. Also, a scroll pane won't work properly. Yes there can be situations when a null layout is valid. The only one I know of is when the user needs the ability to drag components because in this case the location is random so a layout manager can't be used. This question is definitely NOT a reason to use a null layout. This site promotes best practices.